# Finding the value for 2nd TH: header

Tags: javascript

the code below finds the 1st "th" header and assigning the value to Var: Subject. But I want to get the 2nd "th" header text and assign it to Var:Subjct.

I am using `var Subject=$('.tableForEmail th:first').text();` to get the 1st header, but unable to use `var Subjct=$('.tableForEmail th:last').text();` since there will be another header at the bottom of the page.

How can I get the 2nd th header and assign it to `Subjct`.

[image]

Comment: There is not code in your question. Its a screenshot of code. Please add code instead of screenshot, so that we can debug/test your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`:eq(index)` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.

```
$('.tableForEmail th:eq(1)').text();
```

Note: *0-based indexing* hence 1 will target second element

Comment: var Subject=$('.tableForEmail th:eq(0)').text();window.alert(Subject);if(Subject="Request Work Flow"){Subject=$('.tableForEmail th:eq(1)').text()};window.alert(Subject)   In this code it is not responding to my If statement. It is still picking up the eq=1 value when the statement is not true

Comment: Use == for comparison